# boolean search on an array

Tags: c, database, algorithm, database-design

I have multiple arrays with about 100 possible values, ie:

```
a[0] = (a, b, c, d)
a[1] = (a, e)
a[2] = (d, f, g)
```

I want to FASTLY return which arrays contains (a || b) && (d || e)

in this example, 0 and 1

I was thinking about bitwise operations... like representing "abcd" by "1111"; "ad" by "1001", and so on. Then I could solve the "OR" with just a bitwise OR, and then check if both are non-zero

can anyone think on a better solution? this one isn't very pratical since it doesn't seem to be very escalable

are there any DBMS that can do that quickly? I tried with mongodb, but it seems they didn't add the "$and" function yet (doc says it's on version 1.9.1, but I can only download 1.9.0, and it's not stable anyway)

I suppose that's a "boolean search", similar to what google does all the time... so I'm guessing there's a better way (maybe not so fast, but more escalable) than that

Comment: If your arrays will only have abut 100 possible values, the bitwise solution actually seems pretty good.

Comment: As always, in the memory-speed race, if you can afford to duplicate your database, it becomes trivial (at least conceptually). And you stated that you "only" had 1 million array with at most 80 values. So, simply build 80 arrays where the first one contains the index of the arrays containing a, etc... To be honest, I only guess that working with list of integers this will be faster than iterating several times over "bitwise representations"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a bitwise solution works quite nicely for this. Yes, some databases include such a capability, usually named a bitmapped column (or bitmapped index, depending). The usual advice is to apply it to a column that has relatively low cardinality (i.e., a fairly small number of possible values, such as sex).

Answer (score 0):

In what sense is it not scalable?  16 bytes of data per (bit)array isn't bad!  I'm not sure why you want a DBMS for this; you can put binary data in there if you need to (hopefully blocks of arrays), and pull it all out to query.  Unless you're planning on having billions of arrays.

For small numbers of elements, bit logic is fastest.  But if you start going far above 100 values, then keeping the arrays sorted and doing binary (or even linear!) search will be faster.  You'll need to benchmark on your system to find the exact cutoff point, but if your arrays have ~4 elements each, I generally find linear search faster (counting up the occurrences of the elements you're looking for in the boolean logic as you go), and that it beats binary math at about the same point that binary representations also become larger.

Comment: My scalability problem is that if I have, let's say, 80 possible values and 1 million arrays, I'll have to pass thru all the arrays doing the bitwise operation. So it's O(N) on number of data.

Maybe there's a solution that's O(N) (or maybe even O(N^3)) on the number of possible values instead?

Comment: What I can think of is somehow creating a tree of "possible values" that allow boolean search. And the leafs would be all the keys that match this search.

Comment: @Lem0n - You can create a map from each possible value to each array that contains it.  Then you only have to merge and intersect the maps.  But this is likely to be only say 1/20th the number of operations of doing the bitwise thing, and manipulating one bit might be more than 20x faster.

Comment: @Lem0n - Also, keep in mind that you can do three bitwise operations on 16 MB of data in almost no time these days (~1.5 ms on my machine in Java on a single core).  Do you really need to be faster than that?

Answer (score 0):

Store your arrays as a trie, e.g.,

```
a
 b
  c
   d
 e
d
 f
  g
```

Create a trie from the expression as well, e.g.,

```
a
 b
  d
  e
 d
 e
b
 d
 e
```

You can match the latter trie against the former (ignoring any values that aren't in the expression, i.e., 'c', 'f', and 'g') to get the solutions. I leave the details of the trie representation and the matching algorithm up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said the possible values are about 100, but you have lot of arrays, I think a hash table does better than bit level operation(s).
Eg.
 have a hash table set with the values in expression, i.e a, b set to 1 and d, e set to 2.

```
for each array a in arrays      
  for each value v in array
    sum+= ht[v]
    if sum == 3
      print found
      break
```

(the above will not with duplicates though!)
the first for loop can be parallelized, probably with a map-reduce framework or even openMP.
(btw the second for can also be parallelized!)
This should be faster than constructing a bit representation of entire elements in the array and doing AND or OR. You basically benefit with the best case (for eg  a and d are the first 2 elements!) worst case being same for both methods (may be the if done for every element be overhead)